# Collection view as only part of the whole view

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

So I am trying to make it so that only about half of the screen is a collection view but the problem is I don't know how. I know how to do it for a whole view but not just half of one. The top half of the view I have current weather stuff that I want to stay there but then in the collection view I want it to half the next couple of hours of weather stuff. I already have connected to the API that I am using and mostly figured out how to use that. I don't know where to start on this one. I at least have the cell named and the collection view in the storyboard. Sorry for no code I just don't know where to start with this one.

Comment: Are you using a UIViewController with a UICollectionView or are you using a UICollectionViewController?

Comment: @rmaddy I am currently using a View Controller, the view that the project opens with, with a collection view in it. I haven't gotten much else bc I didn't know where to go and I had other stuff I had to do before this on this project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use constraints to set half the screen with collection view and other half with something else, constraint example :

```
NSLayoutConstraints.activate([
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),

    otherView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
    otherView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
    otherView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
    otherView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
])
```

Comment: So after I do the constraints to keep it in place, what do I do? Do I have a separate file for my collection view stuff, like I do for when its the full view, or do I have it just in my view controller?

Comment: Are you talking about the collectionview delegate/datasource? You can keep that in the view controller